# removing index.php and .php extension from all pages using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, indexing

I had added this code in .htaccess for removing .php extension from the url's.Also I had written a code for making blog url seofriendly like https://url.com/posttitle

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #removing extension from url
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
    #blog
    #if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn’t exist, or the directory in the browser doesn’t exist then procede to the rewrite rule below
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog_detail.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]   
</IfModule>
```

I had added links like Home.

Home

How to remove index from url in this case?

Comment: Presumably you’re not actually linking to `index.php` and this is just for SEO and third parties that are linking to the old URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `"/"` in your `href` attribute when navigating to your root (index.html/.php)